# How to block Odd numbered addresses with ACL (Extended ACL)?

Tags: acl, cisco

So I am trying to configure a VPN client on cisco packet tracer but I am having some issues with configuring the ACL. In my task, I am trying to create a VPN tunnel between R4 and R2. I am trying to Block the odd-numbered IP addresses in R2 LAN from using the VPN tunnel. How am I meant to write this access list? I will attach an image to better represent this.

**VPN diagram:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The line in the ACL which would accomplish what you wanted (block odd ip addresses from /24 range):

`access-list 101 deny ip 209.165.1.1 0.0.0.254 dst_ip dst_wildcard`

If you wanted to block all even numbers, you would write this:

`access-list 101 deny ip 209.165.1.0 0.0.0.254 dst_ip dst_wildcard`

This should be the first line in the ACL which is configured on the R2 G0/0 interface, since it should be checked first. After that, you can write rest of the entries, like permitting the whole network to go out of the the S0/0/0 interface and so on.